# Fixing the topic destination in IBM MQ (using WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5)

Tags: websphere, ibm-mq, publish-subscribe, durable-subscription

I have an application running in WAS 8.5.5, which uses pub sub with IBM MQ, and durable subscribers. At a client site, we see intermittent problems re-opening subscriptions to the topic on server startup.

When I look in MQ Explorer at the current subscriptions, I see that the "destination" in each case (which in the end is a queue I think) is being created dynamically by MQ, and has a value like SYSTEM.MANAGED.DURABLE.DXXX1

I would like to fix this value - and set it myself - i.e. use a single queue for topic messages. But I cannot see any way to do this through WAS; it seems that MQ will always manage this itself.

Can anyone help?

Comment: What problems do you see when re-opening subscriptions?

Comment: You can sort of do this if you change the application not to use subscriptions at all, but instead to just read from a queue, and then make the subscriptions with an administrative command in MQ. See https://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21592317